# multiple vertical scrollable divs on multitouch problem

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, multi-touch, interact.js

i try to scroll 2 text fields vertically on a multitouch application, each one works for itself, but as soon as i try to scroll both, only the one touched first works.

is there a workaround here?

maybe an example of a custom scroller?

here's a example, please test on multitouch.

```css
#window {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.window {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}


.scrollable-content {
  height: 180px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}

#footer {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="window">

  <div class="scrollable-content">
    <ul>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  

</div>
<div class="window">
  <div class="scrollable-content">
    <ul>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to always sync both Divs, you could listen for both Div's **scroll** events and then copy the target's **scrollTop** to the other div.

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.scrollable-content');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
    var scrollers = document.querySelectorAll('.scrollable-content');
    for (var i = 0; i < scrollers.length; i++) {
      if ( scrollers[i].isSameNode( event.target ) === false ) {
      scrollers[i].scrollTop = event.target.scrollTop;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#window {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
.window {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
.scrollable-content {
  height: 180px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
#footer {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="window">
  <div class="scrollable-content">
    <ul>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="window">
  <div class="scrollable-content">
    <ul>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to only scroll the second div on a double touch, things get slightly more complicated, assuming you would want both elements to scroll independently of each other's direction and distance.

In short, you'll end up keeping track of **touchstart** events, finding out if it originated inside a div you want to scroll, jotting down the event's Y position, then in the **touchmove** event you'll have to calculate the difference and adjust the Div's **scrollTop** accordingly.

One way of doing it would be like this;

```js
function isDescendant(child,queryString) 
{
    if ( child.matches( queryString ) ) {
        return child;
    }
    var parent = child.parentNode;
    while( parent.matches ) {
        if ( parent.matches( queryString ) ) {
            return parent;
        }
        parent = parent.parentNode;
    }
    return false;
}

var touchedTargets = [];
var touchedData = [];


document.body.addEventListener('touchstart',function( event ){
    var insideTarget = isDescendant( event.target , ".scrollable-content" );
    if ( insideTarget ) {
        var index = touchedTargets.indexOf( event.target );
        if ( index < 0 ) {
            var data = {x:0,y:0,scroller:insideTarget};
            for ( var i=0; i<event.touches.length; i++ ) {
                if ( event.touches[i].target.isSameNode( event.target ) ) {
                    data.x = event.touches[i].clientX;
                    data.y = event.touches[i].clientY;
                }
            }
            touchedTargets.push( event.target );
            touchedData.push( data );
        }
    }
});
document.body.addEventListener('touchend',function( event ){
    var index = touchedTargets.indexOf( event.target );
    if ( index > -1 ) {
        touchedTargets.splice( index , 1 );
        touchedData.splice( index , 1 );
    }
});
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove',function( event ){
    for ( var i=0; i<event.touches.length; i++ ) {
        var index = touchedTargets.indexOf( event.touches[i].target );
        if ( index > -1 ) {
            touchedData[index].scroller.scrollTop = touchedData[index].scroller.scrollTop + ( event.touches[i].clientY - touchedData[index].y );
            touchedData[index].y = event.touches[i].clientY;
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
},{ passive: false });
```

```css
#window {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
.window {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
.scrollable-content {
  height: 180px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
#footer {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="window">
  <div class="scrollable-content">
    <ul>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="window">
  <div class="scrollable-content">
    <ul>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

On **touchstart** the code checks to see if the *event.target* is actually, or is inside, the *.scrollable-content* element.
If this is the case, it will look inside the *event.touches* list to find the corrosponding touch, the touch's clientX, clientY and the *.scrollable-content* element are saved in the *touchedData* array.
The *event.target* is saved in the *touchedTargets* array.

On **touchend** the code checks to see if the *event.target* is inside our *touchedTargets* array and deletes this entry if it's the case.

On **touchmove** the code loops over the event.touches list and checks to see if their *targets*  are inside the *touchedTargets* array.
If this is the case, it will calculate the new **scrollTop** for that particular *.scrollable-content* and update it.

Comment: great answer thank you, I realized that my example works on an iPad, but not on my Windows 10 desktop with the current Chrome browser. On the desktop I can only scroll one div at a time, as soon as I want to scroll both, only the first clicked works. The divs should be scrollable completely independently of each other. The idea is to have two text side by side, and the user can move both while reading, for example original language and translation

What could be the reason?

Comment: it looks like I have to solve the scroll myself with touch events, touching multiple scrollable divs at the same time probably doesn't work. Am I correct? especially for  desktop touch displays?

Comment: Sadly I don't have a desktop touch display and no Mac devices, nor knowledge, to answer on why your previous code works on an iPad but not on Chrome on a desktop.
But here is an [example page](https://dev.luckymouse.nl/multiscroll.html) of the second code snipped I added. You might have to change the direction of scrolling by switching these two around; `( event.touches[i].clientY - touchedData[index].y );`.
I tested the page on Chrome on Android and both divs scrolled individually, according to separate finger movements.

Comment: yes, it works with your javascript, I think the build in sroll behaviour on desktop (overflow: scroll) use only the mouse event, not the touch or pointer events to seperate the touch.

Comment: I integrated your code today in a vuejs multitouch table project, the user can rotate move cards with the scrollable text all at the same time, thanks for your help, took me a step foreward in the touch area.